# Преобразование массива байт в структуру/класс

Tags: c#, массивы

Работаю с USB устройством, от него приходят массивы байт с различными пакетами данных.
Логично, что хочется работать с пакетом не как с массивом байт, а как со структурой/классом с осмысленными полями.

В C++ преобразование байтового массива в структуру или класс делается очень просто:

```
struct A
{
  int param1;
  int param2;
  byte param3;
}

byte Packet[9]; //массив с пакетом, содержащим структуру А

A* pA = (A*)(&Packet[0]);
```

Можно ли в C# сделать преобразование массива байт в структуру/класс похожим образом?

Очень не хочется для каждого пакета писать руками код, заполняющий поля, как тут:

```
 public class ProcessorId
{
    public UInt32 Id0 { get; private set; }
    public UInt32 Id1 { get; private set; }

    public ProcessorId(byte[] data, int offset)
    {         
        Id0 = BitConverter.ToUInt32(data.Skip(offset).Take(4).Reverse().ToArray(), 0);
        Id1 = BitConverter.ToUInt32(data.Skip(offset + 4).Take(4).Reverse().ToArray(), 0);
    }
}
```

Если параметров будет пара десятков - это же столько бесполезной работы, которая в С++ выполняется одной строчкой.

Comment: @yabloko на то он и "управляемый" код, что выкрутасы с указателями как бы не поощряются. :-) Но можно ведь написать обработку на С++ и вызывать и .net Как вам такой вариант?

Comment: > Преобразование массива байт в структуру/класс

десериализация.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> В C++ преобразование байтового массива в структуру или класс делается очень просто:

Очень просто прострелить этим кастом себе ногу, потому что надо учитывать выравнивание и litte-big endianess. А если ваш проц не может читать невыровненные данные, а вы скастуетесь абы куда таким образом, то ногу и вовсе оторвет.

Если очень хочется как в с++, то можно использовать StructLayout Sequential и маршалить

```
public T ReadStruct<T> (Stream fs)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(typeof( T))];
    fs.Read(buffer, 0,  Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)));
    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer,    GCHandleType.Pinned);
    T temp = (T)    Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(T));
    handle.Free();
    return temp;
}
```

С#-way (Для Big-Enddian нужен свой BinaryReader)

```
public ProcessorId(BinaryReader br)
{          
    // где br это new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(data));
    Id0 = br.ReadUInt32();
    Id1 = br.ReadUInt32();
}

// используем
var data = USB.Get();
var br = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(data));

var a1 = new ProcessorId(br);
var a2 = new ProcessorId(br);
var a3 = new ProcessorId(br);
```

Comment: +1 за endianness и выравнивание. И за правильный путь, разумеется.

Comment: Спасибо! Второй вариант очень элегантно выглядит, что даже уже и не хочется связываться с маршалингом.